# How to remove notification banner but leave it in notification centre on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

What i'm doing now:

```
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
```

So my question is, how to leave notification in notification center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always remove it as you are doing and then add it again making sure the NSUserNotificationCenter delegate class implements the shouldPresentNotification method as NO.

- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter*)center
   shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification*)nsNotification {
  return NO;
  }

Comment: Actually this is very flaky since shouldPresentNotification will only show up if the app has focus.